# How to Display specific category list in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a list of categories.
I want to display some specific categories but not all the categories.
How can I do that?

$terms = get_terms(

```
array(

    'taxonomy'   => 'category',

    'hide_empty' => true,

    'number'     => $per_page,

    'offset'     => $offset,

    'parent'     => 10

)
```

also tried this

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) 
{
    if($category->cat_name == "large-post")
    {

    }
    else
    {
        $cats .= $category->cat_name . ', ';
    }
}
echo rtrim($cats, ', ')
```

I know how to select specific categories, but its static. I want it dynamic.
Lets say I have Five categories A,B,C,D,E now I want to exclude D and E but also whenever I want to add new categories that particular category will be listed automatically.

Comment: Hi @Avik Banerjee. As your sample code demonstrates, `get_terms()` searches all terms and `get_the_category()` searches post-specific terms. What kind of search are you looking for? All, or post-specific? What does *I want to display some specific categories* mean? What are your search or filtering criteria? [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) offers the filters `include`, `exclude`, and `exclude_tree`. When you say, *...that particular category will be listed automatically*--listed where? Your solution depends on where you need to see dynamic updates.

Comment: So, I want to exclude two categories from my all categories. I want to show all the categories except those two.

Comment: Why does the [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_terms/#parameters) `exclude` parameter not work for you? (Keep in mind this parameter will not work if you also use the `include` parameter.)